# Get user which is authenticated by Fortify in API routes Laravel 8

Tags: php, laravel-8, fortify

I have a Laravel 8 application that uses Fortify with custom views to login and register users. I have some API routes that I want to get the logged-in user details on them as well. The problem is that I don't want to use Passport and other packages to make the job hard to generate tokens and so on because most of the routes are in the `web.php` and just some routes are on `api.php`, so what I have tried is like below :

```
dd(auth()->guard('api')->user());
```

However, it returns null and...

```
dd(Auth::user());
```

Again returns null. Is there any way to get the authenticated user in the API routes?

Answer (score 1):

In your controller method, you can retrieve the user with these two methods:

```php
public function render(Request $request) {
    $user = $request->user(); // 1
    $user = auth()->user(); // 2
}
```

Comment: Great answer, and so simple in fact !